# HTML table into memory stream

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

I’m currently working on an asp.net page using C#. This page contains a button and once you click you will get a small HTML table with a name of person, cell phone number and email address. What I want to do is in code behind capture this HTML table along with its data in memory stream or other type of streams in order to do some operations. Here's my code

```
<table id="tb" runat="server">
        <tr> 
            <td> Name </td>
            <td> <asp:Label ID="lblName" runat="server" ></asp:Label>  </td>
        </tr>
         <tr> 
            <td> Phone </td>
            <td> <asp:Label ID="lblPhone" runat="server" ></asp:Label>  </td>
        </tr>
         <tr> 
            <td> Email </td>
            <td> <asp:Label ID="lblEmail" runat="server" ></asp:Label>  </td>
        </tr>
     </table>
```

So please, if anyone could help of how to accomplish this process and I will be so thankful

Comment: Sorry if I misunderstood your question but don't you have the table in your Page object already?

Comment: where this HTML table is coming from AND what have you tried?

Comment: I basically fetch some data out of database and bound them

Comment: Are you saying you want to capture the raw html in a stream?

Comment: I want to capture the rendered HTML table into a stream

Comment: which kind of operation? could you be a more specific? may be after that we can get you more.

Comment: I'm trying to put it into memorystream so after that I can convert the exact table with the same format into PDF document using this asp.net library PDF Duo .Net

Answer (score 1):

Well although I don't really understand why do you want to do that, you can do this pretty simply, you have to put id and runat server tag at your table, and you already have that, 
and then render this control to string :

markup:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
  <table id="tb" runat="server">
    <tr> 
        <td> Name </td>
        <td> <asp:Label ID="lblName" runat="server" ></asp:Label>  </td>
    </tr>
     <tr> 
        <td> Phone </td>
        <td> <asp:Label ID="lblPhone" runat="server" ></asp:Label>  </td>
    </tr>
     <tr> 
        <td> Email </td>
        <td> <asp:Label ID="lblEmail" runat="server" ></asp:Label>  </td>
    </tr>
  </table> 

  <hr />
  Rendered table :
  <hr />
  <asp:Label ID="lblRenderedTable" runat="server"></asp:Label>
  <hr />

</form>
```

code behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

  lblName.Text = "User Name";
  lblEmail.Text = "user@domain.com";
  lblPhone.Text = "555-4214";

  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  StringWriter tw = new StringWriter(sb);
  HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(tw);
  tb.RenderControl(hw);
  string tableContents = sb.ToString();

  lblRenderedTable.Text = tableContents;
}
```

Comment: it didn't work. the string variable shows me an empty string !!

Comment: Well maybe this happens because I extended the table to have some asp labels which prevent the complete rendering. When I tried it on a raw HTML table it worked fine. However, when I tried it on a table contains some asp labels it didn't work. So if you have an advice I will be so thanful

Comment: well, I don't know, for me it works with label also, maybe you didn't set label values before rendering table contents to string